# Using applymap in pandas on entire dataframe with if conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I am cleaning the data using applymap on all elements using a custom function and storing the cleaned values in separate column.

```
tag0           tag1                         tag2            tag3
1.Kharif       3.Pest and Disease Management    4.Grasshopper   2.Paddy
1.Kharif       2.Brinjal                    3.Crop Growth Management    
1.Kharif       3.Pest and Disease Management    4.Caterpillar   2.Black Gram
1.Kharif       3.Pest and Disease Management    4.Caterpillar   2.Cotton
```

The above is a part of the entire dataframe.

I wrote the function written below.

```
def tag_cleaner(tag):
'''
this function takes an argument called tag and checks if it starts with 1 then
 it puts it in a new column called season and so on. It is performed row-wise 
and at the end the dataframe will have columnar values
'''
    if tag.startswith('1'):
        df_tags['season'] = tag
    elif tag.startswith('2'):
        df_tags['crop'] = tag
    elif tag.startswith('3'):
        df_tags['maintopic'] = tag
    elif tag.startswith('4'):
        df_tags['subtopic'] = tag
    elif tag.startswith('5'):
        df_tags['issue'] = tag
    else:
        return tag
```

and then applied the applymap function

```
df_tags.applymap(tag_cleaner)
```

I expect the output to be like this

```
season          crop            maintopic                      subtopic
1. Kharif       2.Paddy         3. Pest and Disease Management     4. Grasshopper
1. Kharif       2. Brinjal      3. Crop Growth Management        NA
1. Kharif       2. Black Gram   3. Pest and Disease Management     4. Catterpillar
1. Kharif       2. Cotton       3. Pest and Disease Management     4. Catterpillar
```

The command is able to make the new columns as I wanted, but in all the columns there is same value. It looks like this. This is the same value copied in the entire dataframe.

```
season    crop    maintopic                 subtopic
1.Kharif  2.Paddy 3.Crop Growth Management  4. Caterpillar
```

But I am getting this error

```
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'startswith'", 'occurred at index tag2')
```

I am a beginner and I do not know where am I mistake. I think I am making a logical error in the function that I have defined which is why the last run of the function copies the value to the entire series of the dataframe. Please help.

Comment: the error means that there are some float values in column `tag2`, obviously further down in your entire dataframe. Maybe you could just change it to `if str(tag).startswith` etc. in your function.

Comment: yes, i did that also but when i do that then it gives me the error ```str object has no attribute str```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#reshape DataFrame with remove original columns names
df = df.stack().to_frame('a').reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
#get values before .
df['b'] = df['a'].str.split('.').str[0]
#dictionary for new columns names
d = {'1': 'season', '2': 'crop', '3': 'maintopic', '4':'subtopic','5':'issue'}
#pivoting and get new columns names
df = df.pivot('index','b','a').rename(columns=d).rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None)

print (df)
     season          crop                      maintopic       subtopic
0  1.Kharif       2.Paddy  3.Pest and Disease Management  4.Grasshopper
1  1.Kharif     2.Brinjal       3.Crop Growth Management            NaN
2  1.Kharif  2.Black Gram  3.Pest and Disease Management  4.Caterpillar
3  1.Kharif      2.Cotton  3.Pest and Disease Management  4.Caterpillar
```

EDIT: Error means here there is multiple values with same number per rows, solution is use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with aggregtae function `join`:

```
print (df)
       tag0                           tag1                      tag2  \
0  1.Kharif  1.Pest and Disease Management             4.Grasshopper   
1  1.Kharif                      2.Brinjal  3.Crop Growth Management   
2  1.Kharif  3.Pest and Disease Management             4.Caterpillar   
3  1.Kharif  3.Pest and Disease Management             4.Caterpillar   

           tag3  
0       2.Paddy  
1           NaN  
2  2.Black Gram  
3      2.Cotton  

df = df.stack().to_frame('a').reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
df['b'] = df['a'].str.split('.').str[0]
d = {'1': 'season', '2': 'crop', '3': 'maintopic', '4':'subtopic','5':'issue'}

df = df.pivot_table(index='index',columns='b',values='a', aggfunc=','.join).rename(columns=d).rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None)

print (df)
                                   season          crop  \
0  1.Kharif,1.Pest and Disease Management       2.Paddy   
1                                1.Kharif     2.Brinjal   
2                                1.Kharif  2.Black Gram   
3                                1.Kharif      2.Cotton   

                       maintopic       subtopic  
0                            NaN  4.Grasshopper  
1       3.Crop Growth Management            NaN  
2  3.Pest and Disease Management  4.Caterpillar  
3  3.Pest and Disease Management  4.Caterpillar
```

Comment: I am getting this error ```ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape```